# templated function for registration of event handlers

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I would like to create a function which will register an event handler. EventHandler is registered to listen for a particular eventType.  Method will have a Type and a variable number of parameters required for concrete EventHandler construction. Each concrete event handler will be derived from the abstract class EventHandler.

```
/* E.g this is an abstract eventHandler */
class EventHandler
{
public:
  virtual ~EventHandler() {};
  virtual void OnMessage(const Message *msg) = 0;
};

/* this is an example of derived event handler */
class ServerEventHandler : public EventHandler
{
    int someVar1;
    int someVar2;
public:
  ServerEventHandler(int var1, var2): someVar1(var1), someVar2(var2) {}
  void OnMessage(const Message* msg)
  {
      std::cout << "ServerEventHandler"
  }
};
```

I would like to store event handlers in a vector sorted by their type. I know that the best data structure for this application would be std::multimap, however due to the nature of this problem I am only allowed to use a vector.

I can only think of wrapping eventHandler in another class Listener to be able to do it.
Currently I am using a templated function registerHandler for that.

My gut feeling tells me that this is not an elegant way to do it. For example to be able to find a proper position where the new handler will be placed I will need to create a temporary listener which doesnt sound right to me.
I am using templated function because I would like to do in place construction.

```
struct Listener
{
    int32_t eventType;
    std::unique_ptr<EventHandler> handle;
};

std::vector<Listener> listeners;

template<typename HandlerType, typename ...HandlerParametersType>
int registerHandler(int type, HandlerParametersType&&... handlerParams)
{
    Listener m_searchValue;
    m_searchValue.m_type = type;

    /* Listeners are sorted in the vector by their type */
    auto pos = std::lower_bound(m_listeners.begin(), m_listeners.end(), m_searchValue, [](const Listener& theirs, const Listener& my)
    {
        if (theirs.m_type < my.m_type)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    );

    pos = listeners.emplace(pos, type, std::move(std::make_unique<HandlerType>(std::forward<HandlerParametersType>(handlerParams)...)));
}
```

This is how I will call it

```
registerHandler<ServerEventHandler>(MESSAGE_TYPE_3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: "*however due to the nature of this problem I am only allowed to use a vector.*" -- what *nature* it is?

Comment: and no, you don't need a `m_searchValue` to find `pos`.

Comment: How can I find pos then. lower_bound requires a reference to some object that we will be comparing with

Comment: The nature is I would like to practice how to use lower_bound properly to search through the vector of objects which are sorted by the values of one of their data members. Thank you for your response

Comment: `*lower_bound requires a reference to some object that we will be comparing with*` maybe `int32_t` is a good choice of `some object`? since it doesn't require **same** object

Comment: and no, if that all this question comes from, it's not a good way to ask question, you should ask what you encounter, with [**minimal** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you apple apple, I think I got your hint. I didnt figure out myself that the predicate can take any type of the value to be searched. I changed it to int32_t and it works as expected.

Comment: it's good that you solve the problem :)